# Can you publish a Windows 10 (Universal) app from PhoneGap on Mac?

Tags: windows, cordova, uwp, visual-studio-2017, phonegap-build

I am looking to develop a Windows 10 Universal app based in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript for use on Microsoft Surface tablets primarily. I have found information that says it can be done on [this page](https://phonegap.com/blog/2016/04/25/windows-10-and-phonegap-cli-6_1-now-on-build/), but at the very bottom of the page it says it is in beta. However, I can't seem to find anything more than that post. No updates, or documentation or anything.  Does anyone know if you can do this from the PhoneGap app on Mac OS?

If not, I guess the next best option it to do it on a Windows machine using Visual Studio 2017 and Cordova?

Any information anyone has on this subject would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I am pretty sure you can't build UWP apps on macOS. The reason is quite similar as the reason you cannot build iOS apps on Windows - you could build the JS portion of your code, but the problem is the fact that UWP build tools and SDKs are **OS specific** and unless Microsoft specifically ports them to macOS, they cannot work there.

You could use Parallels and run Windows as second OS, or use a build server to build the app in the cloud. [Visual Studio App Center](https://appcenter.ms/) is a very good solution for you purpose as it allows you to configure a full build pipeline including UWP, iOS and Android builds.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually develop a UWP app using phoneGap on Mac if you are building it using web technologies. (HTML, CSS, Javascript) But you can not build/publish the app on Mac, but if you have a Creative Cloud account, you can use [Phone Gap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) to upload it to the service and have it built there.